# How to fill other text boxes based on value selected in a textbox?

Tags: c#, autocomplete

The code for `textbox1` uses the autocomplete function on `TextChanged` event and displays `Person Name` from database as suggested items in `textbox1`. Now if the user selects a particular name from suggested items in `textbox1`, I want to auto-fill `textbox2` and `textbox3` from database based on value from `textbox1`. How should I do that?

Code of `textbox1` :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"***my connection string***");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTicketDetail";
    SqlDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.Read())
    {
        while (dReader.Read())
            namesCollection.Add(dReader["ContactPerson"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
    }
    dReader.Close();

    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
}
```

Comment: So the auto-complete functionality is working fine, your issue is to get values for other two textboxes based on the selected text in auto complete textbox. am i right?

Comment: Do you skip first line returned by DataReader with purpose? (`if(r.Read(){while(r.Read()...`)

Comment: Updated to fix typos and grammar in the question. Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First cast your code inside a try catch bloc, after that,  in the end of the try bloc,  get the text from the textbox1,  close the previous reader,  and open another reader based on the textbox1 text, fill the textbox2 with the result and close the second reader again,  then do the same for textbox3,